# Problems with AND/OR search in Solr

Tags: solr

I'm facing a weird problem or unexpected behavior in a solr search.

I'm searching for two terms "Goethe" and "Schiller", like this:

```
http://localhost/solr/select/?&q=abstract:%28goethe%20or%20schiller%29&indent=true
```

while this search works fine, I don't want to only be looking in the "abstract" field, but in all fields. So I figured I'd search for

```
http://localhost/solr/select/?&q=goethe%20schiller&indent=true
```

but this only returns hits where both terms appear (AND).

This seems odd, since I did not define "and" to be the defaultOperator in my schema.xml. Even if I explicitly define "OR" there or try something like

```
http://localhost/solr/select/?&q=goethe%20schiller&indent=true&q.op=OR
```

I do not get the desired results, still only those where both terms appear. In summary: I can't perform OR searches, except on explicitly defined fields.

Is there any option I'm missing? Is there any other place I might define the defaultOperator?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to answer my own question: yes, there is an other option. If

```
<str name="mm">100%</str>
```

is set in the requestHandler to 100%, this equals "AND", while 0% equals "OR". I had this set, seems it is the way it was done in older versions of Solr.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

For solr version 5.1.0, the default operator is specified inside schema.xml.

```
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
```

If you want to use AND or OR instead of the default one for a search query, you can define a query parser for it:

```
q={!q.op=AND}+KEYWORDS
```

For older version of solr, yes you have to specify mm(Minimum 'should' match) value. Details can be found [here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin) about mm field